# PHP MySQL script shows no error but won't insert row (more details and different code)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Ok.  So right now, my line of code for inserting looks like this:

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into orders values (".$user_index.",".$order_date.",".$_POST['item_number'].",".$_POST['price'].",".$_POST['tax'].",'".$_POST['pay_method']."')");
```

`$order_date` is a date.  `$user_index` and `$_POST['item_number']` are INTs.  `$_POST['price']` and `$_POST['tax']` are doubles.  `$_POST['pay_method']` is an enum.  At the moment, I really couldn't care less about SQL-injection.  I just want a working page for now.  I'll secure it before it goes live on my website.

My virtual server throws exceptions whether I put in "die(mysqli_error($con))" or not.  However, in this case, it is definitely reaching the code that's in the same if statement after the insert statement.  Yet, when I run this code, everything looks fine but nothing has changed in the database.

I have tried:

```
insert into orders (user_index,order_date,item_number,...) values (...)
```

but it doesn't work that way either.

Finally, yes, I have asked a similar question before.  But as I am new to this website, didn't know if there was a way to edit my old question, and figured this would just be easier since I have more details now and I could possibly get the same people as before to answer this with their questions and troubleshooting steps answered; I just went ahead and posted a new question.

Comment: Have you tried adding single quotes around your insert values? i.e. `'".$user_index."'`

Comment: have you tried executing query in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding ' around your string variables. :

If you knew what the values where you'd add them like this:

```
insert into orders values ('value1','value2' //etc
```

Your code:

```
"insert into orders values (".$user_index.".$value2." //etc
```

Is equivalent to:

```
"insert into orders values (value1,value2 //etc
```

Which is wrong, to fix this add in the ' marks like so:

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into orders values  ('".$user_index."','".$order_date."','".$_POST['item_number']."','".$_POST['price']."','".$_POST['tax']."','".$_POST['pay_method']."')");
```

For future reference a good way to debug dynamically created SQL statements is to assign them to a variable, named something like $sql, then run your mysqli_query($con,$sql). That way if it's not working you can var_dump or echo your $sql variable and see what's really being queried.

Answer (score 0):

if `order_date` is a date you need to pad the string with `'` on both sides.

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into orders values (".$user_index.",'".$order_date."',".$_POST['item_number'].",".$_POST['price'].",".$_POST['tax'].",'".$_POST['pay_method']."')");
```